# Haskell- Placement of variables of functions in functions and `where` statements

Tags: haskell

I know it's not the best explanation but I'm trying my best.

I am struggling to understand the placements of variables and functions in haskell with `where` keywords and function in function type of code.

take this code for example.

```hs
dummy :: Num a => a -> a -> a -> a 

dummy v e = dum 
        where
            dum a@x = v + e + a
```

I thought that the first function is simply executed inside stores the variables v and e. Executes the body with dum where a@x is stored, executed the body doing the addition.

Code below is supposed to take an ordered list and insert a value in correct place.

if I use it like so `insert' 6 [5, 7, 8]`. I thought 6 == x  and  6 == [x]. But then how is the foldr working if it needs a starting value. Because the 3rd code block shows the process. The teacher said the `[6]` is the starting value but I can't seem to use a list as a starting value in foldr.

In summary: With two inputs where are they placed in the body of the function. And how can foldr work here.

```hs
insert' :: Ord a => a -> [a] -> [a]
insert' x = foldr insx [x]
  where
    insx y ys@(z:zs) | z==x && x<y = z:y:zs
                     | otherwise   = y:ys
```

```hs
5 `insx` (7 `insx`(8 `insx` [6]))
5 `insx` (7 `insx`(insx 8 [6])) -- 6==6 && 6<8 = 6:8:[]
5 `insx` (insx 7 6:8:[])        -- 6==6 && 6<7 = 6:7:8:[]
insx 5 (6:7:8:[])                 -- otherwise = 5:6:7:8:[]
```

Comment: I must admit that I’m not _entirely_ sure what you’re asking here, but it may help to know that your definition is equivalent to `insert' x xs = foldr insx [x] xs`. Look up ‘currying’ and ‘partial application’ to learn more about how this works.

Comment: Thank you. I'm looking them up/learning and it seems to help

Answer (score 2):

I’ll go through the evaluation of your example step by step:

```
insert' :: Ord a => a -> [a] -> [a]
insert' x = foldr insx [x]
  where
    insx y ys@(z:zs) | z==x && x<y = z:y:zs
                     | otherwise   = y:ys
```

`insert' 6 [5, 7, 8]` is equivalent to `(insert' 6) [5, 7, 8]` because function application associates to the left.

`insert' 6` is equal to `foldr insx [6]` with `x` = `6`  by the definition of `insert'`.

This is called *eta-reduction*, named after the “eta rule” in lambda calculus. Basically all it means is that if you have a function which can be written like this:

```
f x = g x
```

Where `g` is some expression, then if `g` does not contain `x`, you can simplify this to `f = g`, since `f` is just passing along its parameter directly to `g`. For example:

```
add x y = x + y

-- by definition of infix operators:
add x y = (+) x y

-- by left-association of function application:
add x y = ((+) x) y

-- eta-reduce:
add x   = (+) x

-- eta-reduce again:
add     = (+)
```

So a “two-parameter” definition of type `Int -> Int -> Int` can also be thought of as a one-parameter definition which returns a one-parameter function `Int -> (Int -> Int)`, or a zero-parameter definition (a variable) which is a “two-parameter” function `(Int -> Int -> Int)`. The key thing is that *all functions really have exactly one parameter*, we just have some syntactic sugar for multi-parameter chains of functions.

So the whole expression in your example is equal to `(foldr insx [6]) [5, 7, 8]`. Because function application is left-associative, the parentheses are redundant, so this is the same as `foldr insx [6] [5, 7, 8]`. So `foldr` is *fully applied* here.

The evaluation of foldr then expands to the following:

```
insx 5 (insx 7 (insx 8 [6]))
```

And you can expand the definition of `insx` for each combination of parameters. I’ll start with the rightmost call to `insx`, that is, `insx 8 [6]`, which is equivalent to `insx 8 (6:[])` by the syntax of lists.

By the definition of `insx`, `y` = `8`, `ys` = `[6]`, `z` = `6`, and `zs` = `[]`. So the first guard is `z == x && x < y` = `6 == 6 && 6 < 8`, which is true, so the result is `z:y:zs` = `6:8:[]` = `[6, 8]`.

This gives `insx 5 (insx 7 [6, 8])`. The rightmost call, `insx 7 [6, 8]`, sets `y` = `7`, `ys` = `[6, 8]`, `z` = `6`, and `zs` = `[8]`. The guard evaluates to `6 == 6 && 6 < 7` which again is true, giving `6:7:[8]` = `[6, 7, 8]`.

Finally we have `insx 5 [6, 7, 8]`. Now `y` = `5`, `ys` = `[6, 7, 8]`, `z` = `6`, and `zs` = `[7, 8]`.  The guard is `6 == 6 && 6 < 5`, which is *false*, so we proceed to the next guard. `otherwise` is always true, so we return `y:ys` = `5:[6, 7, 8]` = `[5, 6, 7, 8]`.

Notice that we always have `z == x`; as an exercise, try working through an example input where this part of the condition evaluates to false at some point during the computation.

You can use a value of any type as the “accumulator” parameter for `foldr`, and in this case it is a list. Specifically, `foldr` has the type:

```
foldr :: Foldable t => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
```

Specialised to `t` = `[]` because the *input* is a list, that’s:

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

And in your case it’s further specialised to `b` = `[a]` because the *output* is also a list of the same type:

```
foldr :: (a -> [a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

The `a -> [a] -> [a]` parameter is filled with `insx`, the initial accumulator is `[x]` = `[6]`, and the result is a function `[a] -> [a]` which is then applied to the input `[5, 7, 8]`. And due to typeclass constraints, `a` may be any type in the sets `Num` and `Ord`, such as `Int` or `Integer`.

Answer (score -1):

TDD and stepwise refinement can be used to understand what this program is doing as follows:

```
insert' :: Ord a => a -> [a] -> [a]
f y []                 = [y]
-- Follows to:
f y (z:[]) | (y <= z)  = y : z : []
           | otherwise = z : y : []
-- Follows to:
f y (z:zs) | (y <= z)  = y : z : zs
           | otherwise = z : y : zs
-- Follows to:
insert' y = foldr f [y]
   where
   f y ys@(z:zs) | (y <= z)  = y : ys
                 | otherwise = z : y : zs
-- Follows to:
insert' x = foldr insx [x]
  where
    insx y ys@(z:zs) | z==x && x<y = z:y:zs
                     | otherwise   = y:ys
```